# Place and Style Menu

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

In D7 I could place and style a menu with a few lines in a `mytheme_preprocess_HOOK` function. for example:

```
$variables['page']['navigation'] = array(
  'section' => array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'nav',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => drupal_html_id('navigation'),
      'class' => array(
        'clearfix',
      ),
      'role' => 'navigation',
      'aria-labelledby' => 'main-menu-label',
    ),
    'menu' => array(
      '#theme' => 'links__system_main_menu',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'id' => drupal_html_id('main-menu'),
        'class' => array(
          'links',
          'inline',
          'clearfix',
        ),
      ),
      '#links' => menu_navigation_links('main-menu'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

As you can see this gave great control over markup and attributes for function and styling. The only way I can find to add a menu in D8 is via a block and to style via a TWIG template.

How can I add the menu in a preprocess?

Comment: I guess I would ask, why wouldn't you do it with a Twig template in D8?

Comment: There is less control or I should say defining text for something like the title `H2` in a TWIG file would drastically limit how other functions could interact with the content. As well `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter` and a number of TWIG files means more to manage.